# CKEditor ACF Configuration Help?

Tags: wysiwyg

I am new to configuring CKEditor on **Drupal 7**, and even with the UI, it has always been a pain. I am trying to have it to stop stripping / removing tags, specifically - code, pre, ins del, blockquote, q, dl, dd, dt. I have a test page which I use to test my site's styles and these are getting removed in both Full and Filtered. Grrrr...

Keep in mind I have no idea what I am doing here. Please help me figure this out so I do not waste another day on this. =(

**ACF's extra allowed content**

I have added the following there:

```
br; div; span; header; footer; section; aside; figure; a; img; strong; em; h1; h2; h3; h4; h5; h6; ins; del; cite; q; blockquote; code; pre; table; tr; td; th; thead; tfoot; caption; legend; col; ul; ol; li; dl; dd; dt;</code>
```

**config.js**

I have found config.js and added the following to get it to stop stripping out tags.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) 
{
// Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
// config.language = 'fr';
// config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
config.allowedContent = 'br div span;' + 
    'header footer section aside figure;' + 
    'a[!href]; img[!src,alt,width,height];strong em h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6;' +
     'ins del cite q blockquote code pre;' +
     'table tr td th thead tfoot caption legend col;' + 
     'ul ol li dl dd dt';
config.extraAllowedContent = ' br div(*) span(*);' + 
    'header footer section aside figure;' + 
    'a[!href]; img[!src,alt,width,height];strong em h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6;' +
    'ins del cite q blockquote code pre;' +
     'table tr td th thead tfoot caption legend col;' + 
     'ul ol li dl dd dt';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to disable the content filter altogether, you can use:

```
config.allowedContent = TRUE;
```

Also, make sure you're clearing your Drupal cache AND browser cache. The CKEditor JS files are heavily cached by the browser and I wasted lots of time banging my head against the wall before I realized this.